# Cause fixed div to show/hide on scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide

I have searched around and tried several solutions and nothing is working for me. I am trying to replicate a similar functionality to the "schedule a demo" button seen here: www.bamboohr.com

I currently have the following html, css, and javascript. It seems to work fine in jsfiddle, but not when I implement it into my WordPress child theme. I have pasted the html in the header.php of my child theme, the css into a custom stylesheet, and the javascript loading from another file linked in the header.php.

Can someone please help me figure out why this isn't working?

This is right before the main content `<div>`:

```
    <div class="askFloater">
      <a href="http://workforcematters.hubicle.com" target="_blank">
        <i class="icon-question-sign"></i><br />
        Ask Us Anything
      </a>
    </div>
```

This loads in the `<head>` section:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.workforcematters.com/wp-content/themes/swatch-child-theme/javascripts/askFloater.js"></script>
```

This is in the stylesheet:

```
.askFloater {
display: none;
position: fixed;
bottom: 20px;
right: 0;
width: 70px;
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #3498db;
border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
padding: 16px 16px 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.askFloater a {
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: lowercase;
font-family: 'Muli', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
}

.askFloater:hover {
background-color: #4ea5db;
}
```

This is in the "askFloater.js" file:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 800) {
    $('.askFloater').fadeIn();
} else {
    $('.askFloater').fadeOut();
}

});
```

Comment: Is that really the askFloater `<script>` tag as it shows up in the `<head>`? If so, the malformed extra PHP cruft at the end can't be helping things.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Really need a full code example... Unless you want folks to just randomly guess. And, what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Perhaps you can combine with your existing `$(window).scroll()` in theme JS:

```
// Function that changes the class of the fixed header after some scrolling
function navbarScroll() {
    var header = $(".navbar-inner");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 230) {
            header.addClass("navbar-scrolled");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("navbar-scrolled");
        }

        if (scroll > 800) {
            $('.askFloater').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.askFloater').fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Was able to work around this by utilizing the theme's default go-to-top button, modifying the target url and css. Thanks for the help!